# strpos empty delimiter

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

```
function findit($gbq, $kwords){

$original_file = file_get_contents($gbq);

$keytar = $kwords;
$ckeytar = strtoupper($keytar);
$okeytar = strtolower($keytar);

$arrit = array(
    "original" => $keytar,
    "ocap" => $ckeytar,
    "olow" => $okeytar,
);

if(strpos($original_file, $arrit['original']) == true) {
    $fp = fopen("linkter.html", 'a');
    fwrite($fp, "<a href='" . $gbq . "' style='color:orange;'>" . $gbq . "</a>");
    fclose($fp);
}
elseif(strpos($original_file, $arrit['ocap']) == true) {
    $fp = fopen("linkter.html", 'a');
    fwrite($fp, "<a href='" . $gbq . "' style='color:red;'>" . $gbq . "</a>");
    fclose($fp);
}
elseif(strpos($original_file, $arrit['olow']) == true) {
    $fp = fopen("linkter.html", 'a');
    fwrite($fp, "<a href='" . $gbq . "' style='color:green;'>" . $gbq . "</a>");
    fclose($fp);
}
else{
    echo "String not found";
}
```

}

For some reason it says there is an empty delimiter in the second conditional (the $arrit['ocap'] one).

I've read some other answers, but I haven't found one that works (or that I think would work)

Comment: Have you verified that `$arrit['ocap']` actually has a value?

Comment: I don't use PHP very often, so sorry for not understanding much.

Comment: Don't use `strpos() == TRUE`.  `strpos()` will return 0 if the string is found at position 0, which evaluates to FALSE.  Always use strict comparisons with `strpos()` as in `strpos() !== FALSE`

Comment: Actually, `strpos() !== false` or `strpos() === true` works pretty well.

Comment: I changed it to !== false, but it still says the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you simplify things using `stripos()` instead of `strpos()`, as follows:

```
function findit($gbq, $kwords)
{
    $original_file = file_get_contents($gbq);

    if (stripos($original_file, $kwords) !== false)
    {
        $fp = fopen("linkter.html", 'a');
        fwrite($fp, "<a href='" . $gbq . "' style='color:orange;'>" . $gbq . "</a>");
        fclose($fp);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "String not found";
    }
}
```